# Check if a function has been called from a loop

Tags: python, loops

Is it possible to check dynamically whether a function has been called from within a loop?

Example:

```
def some_function():
    if called_from_loop:
        print("Hey, I'm called from a loop!")

for i in range(0, 1):
    some_function()

some_function()
```

Expected output:

```
> Hey, I'm called from a loop!
```

Comment: Maybe you can workaround to reconduce youself to this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013399/in-python-determine-if-a-function-calls-another-function

Comment: There should be no reason for this to ever be relevant / necessary. Should `[some_function() for i in range(0, 1)]` also show as being in a loop?

Comment: _Why_? What is your end goal?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a loop control approach presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46572323/2245136, with exceptions related to continue and break statements. However, in the case when the function is not called from a loop, I don't want to have these exceptions being thrown.

Comment: That is a terrible idea and would never be expected by anyone else looking at the code. Don't do this.

Comment: Totally agree with @luk2302, however, you could use `inspect` to get the callers frame. Then you can check the AST if there are any for/while loops present. Will not guaranteer that it's called from that loop, but it's a start ;)

Comment: Or you could had a 'caller' argument to your function that takes different values depending on when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to be 100% reliable. It's also rather cumbersome and would have to be written inside the function of interest rather than in its own discrete function for fairly obvious reasons.

We can get the source code for the currently executing .py file

We can also get a stack trace.

Therefore, we can determine the line number in the code from where our function has been called. Thus we can navigate the source code (backwards) taking care to note indentation and see where the indentation decreases and if the line where that occurs starts with either 'for' or 'while' then we were called from within a loop.

So here's the fun:

```
import traceback
import inspect
import sys

def getws(s):
    return len(s) - len(s.lstrip())

def func():
    source = inspect.getsource(sys.modules[__name__]).splitlines()
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    lineno = stack[-2].lineno-1
    isLooped = False
    if (ws := getws(source[lineno])) > 0:
        for i in range(lineno-1, -1, -1):
            if (_ws := getws(line := source[i])) < ws:
                if (tokens := line.split()) and tokens[0] in {'for', 'while'}:
                    isLooped = True
                    break
                if (ws := _ws) == 0:
                    break
    print('Called from loop' if isLooped else 'Not from loop')

def looper():
    for _ in range(1):
        # banana
        func()

def looper2(): # this code is nonsense
    i = 5
    while i > 0:
        if i < 10:
            func()
            break

looper()
looper2()
func()
while True:
    func()
    break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

**Output:**

```
Called from loop
Called from loop
Not from loop
Called from loop
Not from loop
```